# two ListView.separated inside one Row

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a notepad app with a small page view on the side so I trying to add two vertical `ListView.separated` inside one `Row` to make a notepad app looks like that
:[image: notepadview]

but When I am trying to scroll in the main view or the small view I got the following error :

`The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition.`

I want to make Both listViews scrollable and link two listViews by index.

This is my main code :

```
  const Mainview({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainviewState createState() => _MainviewState();
}

class _MainviewState extends State<Mainview> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          //! small pages
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 150,
                    child: CustomPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const SizedBox(
                  height: 3,
                );
              },
              itemCount: 5,
            ),
            flex: 1,
          ),
          //! main pages
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 850,
                    child: CustomPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const SizedBox(
                  height: 3,
                );
              },
              itemCount: 5,
            ),
            flex: 9,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`ScrollController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) for each list view

```
          ...     
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              controller: const ScrollController(),  // <-------------
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 850,
                    child: CustomPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
          ...
```